# How do I go about adding images to a bitmap in Android Studio?

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to be able to add a "Point of interest" onto a bitmap, something like a google map pin which can be clicked on to bring up information.

I just need to know how to go about adding the pin into the space and keep it on the right point of the bitmap (I can pan and zoom on the bitmap)

Sorry, I'm fairly new to Android Studio and thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I wouldn't suggest modifying the bitmap to do this. Create a list of PointOfInterest objects and store their location. Then draw them on top of the map image. No need to modify the bitmap unless you want the user to be able to access it from another app (such as from the image gallery).

Answer (score 0):

You could draw an object on top of your bitmap and implement a touch callback that verifies if you have indeed pressed on your marker.
Here's a simple example:

```
<com.myproject.RedImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

package com.myproject;

public class RedImageView extends View {

    private Paint mPaint;
    private Rect mRect;

    public RedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    //Draw a small white rectangle on top of our red ImageView
    private void init() {
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        mRect = new Rect(20, 20, 120, 120);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawRect(mRect, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        //Simple touch gesture has started
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();
            //Match touch coordinates vs "Point of Interest" aka small white rectangle
            if (mRect.contains(x, y)) {
                Snackbar.make(this, "Clicked white", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll probably have to make a large tab show up because there could be a lot of information on these points and they may need to edit/delete them.

I've played around with this code and it's got some useful stuff, but I still can't get anywhere. Do you know anything about adding an image from the drawable folder on top of a bitmap (not in the bitmap, like an overlay) that stays at the coordinates of the bitmap (because I can pan and zoom the bitmap) and responds to touch at all?